# TripleDES in CFB mode using Crypto++ and .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, crypto++, tripledes

I am trying to get same result using TripleDES using C++ app which has [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/) and .NET app which uses [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx). I tried setting Key and IV the same but I am getting different results.

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112036/tripledes-encoding-in-c-sharp-and-crypto-differs), but there is no clear answer.

Here is C++ example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


#include "dll.h"
#include "mybase64.h"

using namespace std;

USING_NAMESPACE(CryptoPP)



int main()
{
std::cout << "Crypto++ Example" << endl;

std:cout << "TEST" << endl;


const int textSize = 4;
const int keySize = 24; 

byte iv[] = { 240, 4, 37, 12, 167, 153, 233, 177 };
byte key[] = {191, 231, 220, 196, 173, 36, 92, 125, 146, 210, 117, 220, 95, 104, 154, 69, 180, 113, 146, 19, 124, 62, 60, 79};


byte encryptedText[textSize];

char cText[] = {'T', 'E', 'S', 'T'};

byte* text = new byte[textSize];

for (int ndx = 0; ndx<4; ndx++)
{
    text[ndx] = (byte)cText[ndx];
}


CFB_FIPS_Mode<DES_EDE3>::Encryption encryption;

encryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, keySize, iv);

encryption.ProcessString(encryptedText, text, 4);

string encoded;

encoded = base64_encode(encryptedText, 4);

cout << encoded << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
 }
```

which produces following result:

```
K3zUUA==
```

Here is C# example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace TripleDESExample
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string message = "TEST";
           byte[] iv = { 240, 4, 37, 12, 167, 153, 233, 177 };
           byte[] key = { 191, 231, 220, 196, 173, 36, 92, 125, 146, 210, 117, 220, 95, 104, 154, 69, 180, 113, 146, 19, 124, 62, 60, 79 };

           byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

           using (var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
           {
               tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
               tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

               tdes.IV = iv;
               tdes.Key = key;

               using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
               {
                   using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(ms, tdes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                   {
                       crypto.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                       crypto.Close();

                    }


                    Array.Copy(ms.ToArray(), data, data.Length);

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Encrypted: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(data)));

               }
           }

           Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
 }
```

Which produces following result:

```
K7nXyg==
```

So you can see that they produce different result.

```
K7nXyg==  
K3zUUA==
```

Can anyone point what could be the issue for them showing different result.

If possible please provide example code.

---------------------UPDATE 4/27/2017-----------------------------------------

Now tried using a little differently implementation of .NET giving me different result as well...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace TripleDESExample
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           string message = "TEST";


        byte[] iv = { 240, 4, 37, 12, 167, 153, 233, 177 };
        byte[] key = { 191, 231, 220, 196, 173, 36, 92, 125, 146, 210, 117, 220, 95, 104, 154, 69, 180, 113, 146, 19, 124, 62, 60, 79 };



        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider1 = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        cryptoServiceProvider1.Key = key;
        cryptoServiceProvider1.IV = iv;
        cryptoServiceProvider1.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        cryptoServiceProvider1.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider2 = cryptoServiceProvider1;


        byte[] inArray = cryptoServiceProvider2.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cryptoServiceProvider2.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Encrypted: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(inArray, 0, inArray.Length)));



        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
 }
```

which gives me:

```
K7nXyp+x9kY=
```

Why?

------UPDATE 4/28/2017-----------

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21877/Applied-Crypto-Block-Ciphers) article describes very well Crypto++ implementation.

When I try to increment BlockSize and FeedbackSize I get following error:

[image]

---

Based on the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cryptopp-users/ycLWj3Dmdjs) it seems like .NET TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider uses CipherMode.CFB in 8-bit while Crypto++ uses it with 128-bit. When trying to set FeedbackSize for .NET higher it throws exception.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The issue is likely the feedback size. I believe .Net uses a small feedback size, like 8-bits, for CFB mode. Crypto++ uses the full block size for CFB mode. I'd recommend getting a baseline using CBC mode. Once you arrive at the same result in .Net and Crypto++, then switch to CFB mode and turn knobs on the feedback size.

Comment: Do you have example how to accomplish this?

Comment: *"it sounds like issue might be with message padding..."* - I don't believe CFB mode is padded. The problem is likely feedback size. I'm not a Windows developer, so I can't help with the .Net side of things. A .Net guy will have to tell you how to set feedback size. By the way, why does [`FeedbackSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes(v=vs.110).aspx) not work? What exception do you get?

Comment: I tried to use all the options in .NET for padding still not producing same result as Crypto++

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> > The issue is likely the feedback size. I believe .Net uses a small feedback size, like 8-bits, for CFB mode. Crypto++ uses the full block size for CFB mode. I'd recommend getting a baseline using CBC mode. Once you arrive at the same result in .Net and Crypto++, then switch to CFB mode and turn knobs on the feedback size.
>
> Do you have example how to accomplish this?

You can find examples of [CBC Mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki. Other wiki pages of interest may be [TripleDES](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/TripleDES) and [CFB Mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CFB_Mode).

You can also find test vectors for these modes of operation on the [NIST website](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/block-ciphers.html).

You really need to get to a baseline. You should not use random messages and random keys and ivs until you achieve your baseline.

---

Here's an example of using a less-than-blocksize feedback size in Crypto++. The example is available at [CFB Mode](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CFB_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki (we added it for this answer). You will have to dial in your parameters random parameters (but I suggest you baseline first with something like the NIST test vectors).

You should be wary of using a feedback size that is smaller than the block size because it can reduce the security of the block cipher. If given a choice, you should increase the feedback size for Mcrypt or .Net; and not reduce the feedback size for Crypto++.

```
SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH), iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
memset(key, 0x00, key.size());
memset(iv, 0x00, iv.size());

AlgorithmParameters params = MakeParameters(Name::FeedbackSize(), 1 /*8-bits*/)
                                      (Name::IV(), ConstByteArrayParameter(iv));

string plain = "CFB Mode Test";
string cipher, encoded, recovered;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
   cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

   CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption enc;
   enc.SetKey( key, key.size(), params );

   StringSource ss1( plain, true, 
      new StreamTransformationFilter( enc,
         new StringSink( cipher )
      ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
   ); // StringSource
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& ex )
{
   cerr << ex.what() << endl;
   exit(1);
}

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

// Pretty print cipher text
StringSource ss2( cipher, true,
   new HexEncoder(
      new StringSink( encoded )
   ) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource
cout << "cipher text: " << encoded << endl;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
   CFB_Mode< AES >::Decryption dec;
   dec.SetKey( key, key.size(), params );

   // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
   //  padding as required.
   StringSource ss3( cipher, true, 
      new StreamTransformationFilter( dec,
         new StringSink( recovered )
      ) // StreamTransformationFilter
   ); // StringSource

   cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& ex )
{
   cerr << ex.what() << endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
$ ./test.exe
plain text: CFB Mode Test
cipher text: 2506FBCA6F97DC7653B414C291
recovered text: CFB Mode Test
```

---

> So you can see that they produce different result.
>
> K7nXyg==
>   K3zUUA==

The following reproduces `K7nXyg==`, but its not clear to me that's what you want. You really should get to your baseline. Then you can tell us things like a key with no parity and an 8-bit feedback size.

```
const byte key[] = { 191, 231, 220, 196, 173, 36, 92, 125,
                     146, 210, 117, 220, 95, 104, 154, 69,
                     180, 113, 146, 19, 124, 62, 60, 79 };
const byte  iv[] = { 240, 4, 37, 12, 167, 153, 233, 177 };

ConstByteArrayParameter cb(iv, sizeof(iv));
AlgorithmParameters params = MakeParameters(Name::FeedbackSize(), 1 /*8-bits*/)
                                           (Name::IV(), ConstByteArrayParameter(iv, sizeof(iv)));

string plain = "TEST";
string cipher, encoded, recovered;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
   cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

   CFB_Mode< DES_EDE3 >::Encryption enc;
   enc.SetKey( key, sizeof(key), params );

   StringSource ss1( plain, true, 
      new StreamTransformationFilter( enc,
         new StringSink( cipher )
      ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
   ); // StringSource
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& ex )
{
   cerr << ex.what() << endl;
   exit(1);
}

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

// Pretty print cipher text
StringSource ss2( cipher, true,
   new Base64Encoder(
      new StringSink( encoded )
   ) // HexEncoder
); // StringSource
cout << "cipher text: " << encoded << endl;

/*********************************\
\*********************************/

try
{
   CFB_Mode< DES_EDE3 >::Decryption dec;
   dec.SetKey( key, sizeof(key), params );

   // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
   //  padding as required.
   StringSource ss3( cipher, true, 
      new StreamTransformationFilter( dec,
         new StringSink( recovered )
      ) // StreamTransformationFilter
   ); // StringSource

   cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;
}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& ex )
{
   cerr << ex.what() << endl;
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I need to reproduce this in .NET, I am not trying to adjust Crypto++ to match .NET but the other way around. Examples you provided both in C++ and I don't have issue reproducing them. I need to get .NET implementation to show the same as Crypto++. Can you add baseline NIST example?

Comment: I am getting error on AlgorithmParameters I am using Crypto++ 5.3 which is FIPS validated.